# Symfony Kernel Request is too slow

Tags: php, performance, symfony

I am developing an application using Symfony framework. I am at first steps where I can login with a user and display a page with some data retrieved from database some CSS and JavaScript.

For some reason my request is counting too long execution time without an obvious reason.

I would like your help in order to understand why is this happening.

Attached you may find profiler results.

[image: Image - 1]
[image: Image - 2]

Comment: The firewall seems to be responsible for the long time. Do you have complex routing?

Comment: I didn't manage to find a solution for that.Are you facing this problem too?

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by your security configuration in `security.yml`, more preciselly by your password encoding algorithm configuration. For example if you use the *bcrypt* algorithm with a high cost (over 13).